# Why does the rawquery in my sqlite database give me the wrong person?

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite, android-cursor

I made an app in eclipse for android where you can fill in a person's information like name, email, adress, etc. In this app I need to include a search-button, which will search for a person that is saved in the database when one or more pieces of information are known. E.g. when I only remember the email-adress of a person who is saved in the database, I need to be able to find that person by searching for a matching email. This is the code I used for doing so:

```
public Person getPerson(String naam, String adres, String email, String geslacht,
        String leeftijd, String geboortedatum){
    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor curs=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM personen WHERE name = ? OR adress = ? "
            + "OR email = ? OR gender = ? OR age = ? OR birthday = ?", 
            new String[]{naam==null?"'":naam, adres==null?"'":adres, 
                    email==null?"'":email, geslacht==null?"'":geslacht, 
                            leeftijd==null?"'":leeftijd, geboortedatum==null?"'":geboortedatum});
    if(curs!=null)
        curs.moveToFirst();
```

The reason I changed the args[] when it included a null-value is that otherwise the rawQuery won't work. This code however, does not return the person I was searching for, but it simply returns the very first person in the database. 
When simplifying the code by making the query search for a persons name only it actually does return the person with that name:

```
Cursor curs=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM personen WHERE name = ?", new String[]{naam});
if(curs!=null)
   curs.moveToFirst();
```

What is wrong with the first rawQuery and why doesn't it return the person I'm looking for, but simply the first person in the database, whereas the second rawQuery does return the right person?

Comment: using 'or' will return the first row where one of the conditions is verified, but your 'curs.moveToFirst();' will return only the first row, so you have to make a while

Comment: you have persons with properties in common. look at the size of your cursor.

Comment: curs.moveToFirst(); return only the first row of the result

Comment: @njzk2 thanks for your comment. I feel really stupid now, because I figured it would be something like that but I didn't realize that the parameter age is determined by a spinner which automatically returns 0-9 years when no birthday is given. That's probably the property they all have in common because I tried to make it work by solely giving all persons a name in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with the OR. Could you try AND and see ? Because OR is usually means optional. What i mean by optional is, you are telling sql engine to return the person with any of those attributes it matches too. So you are not restricting but giving many possibility abd OR is ending up with many users and therefore its getting the first one. Dont use OR. Try creating a query that returns a unique result you want.

Comment: I thought it would be something like that as well, but with AND i get an error. This is probably because the null-values are really stored as null-values in the database, but I gave the parameters in the args[] another value when they were null, so there will never be an exact match with the values in the database. That is why I chose to use OR, because I thought it would only search for the matching parameters in that case..

Comment: Okay. Then why not search for the one with values Or I have an idea you can search where IS NOT NULL. like : SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE YourColumn IS NOT NULL; So it will consider or compare the one with values only.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public Person getPerson(String naam, String adres, String email, String geslacht,
            String leeftijd, String geboortedatum){
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor curs=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM personen WHERE name = ? OR adress = ? "
                + "OR email = ? OR gender = ? OR age = ? OR birthday = ?", 
                new String[]{naam==null?"'":naam, adres==null?"'":adres, 
                        email==null?"'":email, geslacht==null?"'":geslacht, 
                                leeftijd==null?"'":leeftijd, geboortedatum==null?"'":geboortedatum});
        if(curs!=null)
            if (curs.moveToFirst()){
               while(curs.hasNext){
//Your code, this will return all the rows of your sql,use curs.next() to get a row
}
```